# Connecting phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

Can anyone help me solve this SQL error?
And how do I connect it to my database in phpmyadmin using xampp?
Feel free to correct my code if you think something is wrong with it.

```vb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Form1
Dim con As SqlConnection
Dim com As SqlCommand

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    con = New SqlConnection
    con = New SqlCommand
    con.ConnectionString = "initial catalog=student;user id=sa;pwd="
    con.Open()
    con.Connection = con
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If TextBox1.Text = " " Or TextBox2.Text = " " Or TextBox3.Text = " " Then
        MsgBox("Please fill all the details")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    com.CommandText = "insert into stud values('" & TextBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "','" & TextBox3.Text & "')"
    com.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MsgBox("1 record is stored successfully")
    TextBox1.Clear()
    TextBox2.Clear()
    TextBox3.Clear()
End Sub
End Class
```

[image]

Comment: Have you read the error messages and looked at the lines it mentions?  `con` can only be a Command **or** a Connection object.  There is plenty more wrong. you should do some research on IDisposable, COnnection Pooling and SQL parameters

Comment: Also MySQL and SQL Server are two very different things - none of the `System.Data.SqlClient` objects will work with MySQL.  You'll also want to visit www.connectionstrings.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use **MySqlConnection**, not SqlConnection. SqlConnection is used for SQL Server. It can be downloaded from Nuget packages.

Comment: When giving an answer it is preferable to give [some explanation as to WHY your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is the one.